# Jquery Upload Image Plugin ex. Uploadify

Tags: jquery, mysql, uploadify

I've been trying to find a RECENT tutorial on an image upload tool, preferably using Jquery, that allows you to upload/retrieve imgs using Mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This url may help you.

http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: Lovely, except the `Error runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference` messages :)